# Wiki de comunidad como limitante para obtener reputación

Tags: soporte, wiki-de-comunidad

Estaba respondiendo una pregunta y marco la casilla wiki de comunidad y me sale lo siguiente:
¿Estás seguro de que deseas convertir esta publicación en wiki de comunidad?

Al hacerlo, se quitará la propiedad explícita y ya no ganarás reputación por los votos a favor que la publicación reciba. Una vez que se guarda, esta opción no se puede desactivar sin la asistencia de un moderador.

¿Realmente necesitamos molestar a un moderador para eliminar esta opción?
Además ¿qué es una publicación wiki comunidad?